# How to create dropdownlist with names and ID's (as value) from the database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using a model for validation on my form in MVC.
I want to have a dropdown box with politicus names as the display and the politicus ID as the value="id" for each option...

This is my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Je moet minimum één politicus selecteren")]
public int politicusId1 { get; set; }
```

My view code that gives only politicus names , without the value="id"

```
@foreach(var pol in politici){
    polnamen.Add(pol.Account.voornaam + " " + pol.Account.achternaam);
    polvalues.Add(pol.politicusID.ToString());
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.politicusId1, new SelectList(polnamen, polvalues))
```

So basicly, I need one politicusId to be selected from a dropdownlist in HTML, while displaying the names of the politici, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a property on my view model which contains the select list items:

```
public IList<SelectListItem> Politici { get; set; }
```

Then in the controller populate the collection:

```
model.Politici = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var pol in politici)
{
    var item = new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = pol.Account.voornaam + " " + pol.Account.achternaam,
        Value = pol.politicusID
    }

    model.Politici.Add(item);
}
```

(`model` in this example in an instance of your view model)

And finally in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.politicusId1, Model.Politici)
```